# LINQ query continues to return null after 1st successful call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an upload function in my ASP.NET MVC web application which allows a user to upload a document. The system then uses various OCR APIs to read data from the uploaded document, this data is then saved in the "SecondarySchoolSurvey" table in the database. I have a LINQ query in the upload code which finds a row in the database "SecondarySchoolSurvey" table that matches the Id passed in. Various fields in this row are then updated and saved back into the database.

Now this upload function works fine first time. Although if I try to use the upload function again (without restarting the IIS server) then it  throws the following error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

After setting various break points I noticed that the LINQ query: `var s1 = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);` returns null the 2nd time it is called i.e. it does not find the record which matches the Id passed in, even though it exists in the database.

So for now, I need to reset the web app IIS server after every time I want to test the upload function. Otherwise this LINQ query with return `null` the 2nd time I try upload a document. Has anybody seen anything like this before? I'm not sure how useful it will be providing code but here is one of the class, the one which contains the LINQ query:

```
public class SurveyCheckboxAnswers
{
    private RDSContext db = new RDSContext();

    //Adds Question 2 answer
    public void AddQ2Answer(SurveyCheckboxCollections checkboxes, int id)
    {
        //find Survey record in db which matches id in order to update with checkbox data
        var s1 = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);

        CheckboxData q2Male = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q2Male"];
        CheckboxData q2Female = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q2Female"];
        CheckboxData q2Other = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q2Other"];
        CheckboxData q2DontWantToSay = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q2DontWantToSay"];

        //numbers of checkboxes marked for validation
        int checkboxValidaiton = 0;

        //update SecondarySchoolSurvey checkbox answers in database with IsChecked values from checkbox dictionary 
        if (q2Male.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q2 = Gender.Male;
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q2Female.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q2 = Gender.Female;
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q2Other.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q2 = Gender.Other;
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q2DontWantToSay.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q2 = Gender.None;
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }

        //validate only 1 checkbox has been marked 
        if(checkboxValidaiton == 0)
        {
            s1.Flag = true;
            s1.FlagContent += "| Question2: no checkboxes marked. ";
        }
        else if (checkboxValidaiton > 1)
        {
            s1.Flag = true;
            s1.FlagContent += "| Question2: more than 1 checkboxes marked. ";
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

    }

    //Adds Question 6 answer
    public void AddQ6Answer(SurveyCheckboxCollections checkboxes, int id)
    {
        //find Survey record in db which matches id in order to update with checkbox data
        var s1 = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);

        CheckboxData q6Higher = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q6Higher"];
        CheckboxData q6Ordinary = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q6Ordinary"];
        CheckboxData q6Other = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q6Other"];


        //numbers of checkboxes marked for validation
        int checkboxValidaiton = 0;     

        if (q6Higher.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q6a = MathLevel.Higher;
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q6Ordinary.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q6a = MathLevel.Ordinary;
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q6Other.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q6a = MathLevel.Other;
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }

        //validate only 1 checkbox has been marked 
        if (checkboxValidaiton == 0)
        {
            s1.Flag = true;
            s1.FlagContent += "| Question6: no checkboxes marked. ";
        }
        else if (checkboxValidaiton > 1)
        {
            s1.Flag = true;
            s1.FlagContent += "| Question6: more than 1 checkboxes marked. ";
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Adds Question 7 answer
    public void AddQ7Answer(SurveyCheckboxCollections checkboxes, int id)
    {
        //find Survey record in db which matches id in order to update with checkbox data
        var s1 = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);

        CheckboxData q7Physics = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q7Physics"];
        CheckboxData q7Biology = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q7Biology"];
        CheckboxData q7Chemistry = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q7Chemistry"];
        CheckboxData q7Science = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q7Science"];
        CheckboxData q7None = checkboxes.SecondarySchoolCheckboxes["Q7None"];

        //numbers of checkboxes marked for validation
        int checkboxValidaiton = 0;

        if (q7Physics.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q7 = "Physics";
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q7Biology.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q7 += "Biology";
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q7Chemistry.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q7 += "Chemistry";
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q7Science.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q7 += "Science Junior";
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }
        if (q7None.IsChecked)
        {
            s1.Q7 += "None";
            checkboxValidaiton++;
        }

        //validate only 1 checkbox has been marked 
        if (checkboxValidaiton == 0)
        {
            s1.Flag = true;
            s1.FlagContent += "| Question7: no checkboxes marked. ";
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: In each function, try wrapping the code in a using statement: `using (var context = new RDSContext())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here most likely lies in the fact you are using a private variable for the db context. The appropriate way to open/close the connection to your db using a context is to use a using statement like so:

```
using(var db = new RDSContext())
{
    //...Do work here with your context
}
```

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use using if you want all the resources that the context controls to be disposed at the end of the block. When you use using, the compiler automatically creates a try/finally block and calls dispose in the finally block.

Comment: so should I delete `private RDSContext db = new RDSContext();` and then wrap each method in `using(var db = new RDSContext())` blocks?

Comment: Yessir! @craig2020

Comment: @craig2020. Yes.

Comment: Another piece of advice is to only keep the using statement open for as long as you need it. You goal should always be to open/close the connection as fast as possible. @craig2020

Comment: Perfect guys, thanks a lot! I tried to simply use db.Dispose() which is obviously not the recommended way to open/close db connections. It is working perfectly now after wrapping each methods code in using blocks

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is running but is returning null, your db context is likely valid. That means the issue is likely the query itself. I suspect that on subsequent runs, you are passing in a different `id` that has no record in your database. Asking the db for the first record, if any, that matches the supplied `id` therefor returns null. Use a breakpoint to inspect both the provided `id` and the generated sql. Check in your db that you have a row for the id.

On another note, I would suggest that you use the method `First` or `Single` instead of `FisrtOrDefualt` if you expect the query to always return a row. This will throw an error if there are no matching rows, which guarantees that you have a not-null result returned if no error is thrown. The advantage is that after the method you now know that there was a matching row, whereas otherwise you may have to include a null check.

There is a great table on these operators [here](http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/)